Android Auto Car Api Level Distribution
I'd like to use some Android Auto Templates, which are available from newer Car API levels, e.g.:
@RequiresCarApi(7)
MapWithContentTemplate

Currently, my minCarApiLevel is set to 2 and I'm considering to raise it to 7 to be safe.
However I cannot find any information about current Car API levels distribution (similar to Android API levels distribution, which can be seen when creating new project in Android Studio).
All I could find is a list of vehicle models supporting Android Auto, but it is almost impossible to find supported Car API level: https://www.android.com/auto/compatibility/
How can I find out, how many vehicles will be cut off, if I raise my minCarApiLevel?

The Car API level for Android Auto is determined by the version of the Android Auto app installed on the user’s device.

For now, we decided to make our own research before updating minCarApiLevel: we will track car API level with application's analytics to gather statistics.
